# Too many inputs specified for the "scale" filter when joining 3 videos side by side

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm using this ffmpeg command to join 3 videos into 1 playing side-by-side but I'm getting this error, I've wasted a bunch of time trying to search for the problem but I just can't seem to find it.

```
ffmpeg -v error -i VIDEO0 -i VIDEO1 -i VIDEO2 -preset veryfast -filter_complex [0:v][1:v][2:v]scale=1280:-1[b],[v0][v1][b]xstack=inputs=3:layout=0_0|w0_0|0_h1[out] -map "[out]" -map 0:a OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, it was that I was sending [0:v] and [1:v] into the scale filter

**Edit**

The full command would be something like:

```
ffmpeg -v error -i video0.webm -i video1.webm -i video2.webm -preset veryfast -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1280:-1[b],[b]xstack=inputs=3:layout=0_0|w0_0|w0_h1[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a OUTPUT.webm
```

Comment: can you provide the correct syntax, please?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the full command. Sorry it took me so long to see this...